# issue including php.ini in cron job

Tags: php, oauth, cron, ini

Cron job continues to fail after including the ini in the cron command. Including the ini is necessary because I enabled OAuth in the ini which is needed for the php script.

Here is the cron command:

```
/usr/bin/php -c /home7/username/public_html/php.ini -q /home7/username/public_html/subdomain/processes/api/refresh.php >>/home7/username/public_html/subdomain/processes/api/APIoutput.txt
```

However, I still get the error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in /home7/username/public_html/subdomain/processes/classes/WithingsAPI_Lib/WBSApi.php on line 26

If I run the script manually in the browser, it runs fine, why does it fail in the cron job, even if I include the php.ini?

Comment: Maybe it's because you included the OAuth class using a relative path?
If this is the case try to change include 'OAuth.php' by include \_\_dir\_\_ . "/OAuth.php" (assuming the filename is OAuth.php)

Comment: or the php.ini you're including doesn't have the same include_path that your SAPI-based php has.